# JQMIGRATE and Wordpress Elementor: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function. jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor, jqmigrate

I have a Jquery error on my WordPress website page using Elementor which is preventing the same-page anchor links to work.

Error on google console:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function
at init.run (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at Function.n.fx.timer (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at qb (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at HTMLParagraphElement.g (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at Function.dequeue (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at HTMLParagraphElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at a.fn.init.queue (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
```

If you click in any of the anchor links, the google console shows the message below, with a growing number of errors - see the image.

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function
at init.run (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at n.fx.tick (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
```

Image of the error on google console:

[image]

Can anyone help?
Thank you!